# Class moderncv with German bibliography without numbered bibitems

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, moderncv, german

With documentclass `moderncv` one can include a list of published papers. If you try this is German one could use bibliography style `gerplain` getting some errors (solved in question [Problem with modernCV and bf inside bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67018/problem-with-moderncv-and-bf-inside-bibliography)) but with a missing "und" (German and) or ";" as usual in Germany. (You can try with the following MWE.)

With the styles `plaindin` or `unsrtdin` one gets the right bibliography, but now you have leading bibitems `[1]`, `[2]` etc.

Is there a way to get rid of these bibitems without creating a new `bst` file? Or to have the bibitems right justified?

The MWE for testing:

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{book1,
  author    = {John Doe and John Smith},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  edition   = {edition},
  year      = {year},
}

@BOOK{book2,
  author    = {John Doe and Eva Smith},
  title     = {Title2},
  publisher = {Publisher2},
  edition   = {edition},
  year      = {year},
}

@MISC{misc1,
  author = {John Doe},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {year},
}

@MISC{misc2,
  author = {John Doe and Max Musterfrau},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {year},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}  %change the width of the column with the dates

%  for numerical labels: I do not want them!
%\renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                  
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                          
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                           
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                         
\email{john@doe.org}                           
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                     
\extrainfo{additional information}    
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a} % change image name 
\quote{Some quote}                    

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman} % German cv

\makecvtitle

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
\renewcommand{\refname}{Veröffentlichungen}  % instead "Publications"
\nocite{*}                   % cite all entrys in bib file
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin} % german bib styles: gerplain, plaindin, unsrtdin
                             % compare with plain (wrong "and" instead German "und")
                             % gerplain: -> 12 errors \sc undefined, missing "`und"' or "`;"'
                             % plaindin, unsrtdin: unwanted bibitems
\bibliography{\jobname}      % bib file \jobname.bib

\end{document}
```

I used image `example-image-a` from package [`MWE`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) for the photo. You will get a result like:

> ```
> [1]          Doe, John ; Smith, John: Title. edition. Publisher, year
> ```

I would prefer to have:

> ```
>              Doe, John ; Smith, John: Title. edition. Publisher, year
> ```

or (second choise):

> ```
>         [1]  Doe, John ; Smith, John: Title. edition. Publisher, year
> ```

In the resulting `bbl` file you can find:

```
\bibitem[1]{book1}
\textsc{Doe}, John ; \textsc{Smith}, John:
\newblock \emph{Title}.
\newblock edition.
\newblock Publisher, year
```

Using `biblatex` is not possible because class `moderncv` is not compatible with it as I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first optional argument of the command `\bibitem` is executing by the command `\@biblabel` which have one mandatory argument.

My suggestion uses commands with `@` and so you must handle them as describe in the question: [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

For the first choice you can gobble the mandatory argument by the following assignment:

```
 \let\@biblabel\@gobble
```

For the second choice you can use a small trick. The justification of the bibliography label is done by `\@biblabel{#1}\hfill`. To gobble the `\hfill` to get your requested alignment you can use `\hfill` as part of the definition of `\@biblabel`

```
\def\@biblabel#1\hfill{[#1]}
```

In the mwe below I have implemented both solutions:

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{book1,
  author    = {John Doe and John Smith},
  title     = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  edition   = {edition},
  year      = {year},
}

@BOOK{book2,
  author    = {John Doe and Eva Smith},
  title     = {Title2},
  publisher = {Publisher2},
  edition   = {edition},
  year      = {year},
}

@MISC{misc1,
  author = {John Doe},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {year},
}

@MISC{misc2,
  author = {John Doe and Max Musterfrau},
  title  = {Title},
  year   = {year},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin} 
% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}                  
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                          
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                           
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                         
\email{john@doe.org}                           
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                     
\extrainfo{additional information}    
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a} % change image name 
\quote{Some quote}                    

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman} % German cv
\makecvtitle
% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
\renewcommand{\refname}{Veröffentlichungen}  % instead "Publications"
\nocite{*}                   % cite all entrys in bib file
\makeatletter
\let\@biblabel\@gobble
\makeatother
\bibliography{\jobname}      % bib file \jobname.bib

\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1\hfill{[#1]}
\makeatother
\bibliography{\jobname}      % bib file \jobname.bib

\end{document}
```

[image]